# Numpy randint within PySpark udf returning unexpected values

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I created a udf to generate random ten-digit integers in a column within a PySpark dataframe:

```
phone_udf = F.udf(lambda: np.random.randint(low = 1111111111, high = 9999999999), T.IntegerType())

households = sc.union([sc.parallelize([[j]
                          for j
                          in np.random.choice(household_sizes, size=partition_size, p=hh_size_probs).tolist()])
                          for i in range(partition_count)]).toDF(["_household_members"])\
               .limit(nhouseholds)\
               .withColumn("household_id", F.row_number().over(w))\
               .withColumn("_hoh_last_name_id", (F.rand() * name_count).cast("int"))\
               .withColumn("_hh_address_id", (F.rand() * address_filtered_count).cast("int"))\
               .withColumn("phone", phone_udf())
```

However, the resulting dataframe's "phone" column includes integers of all different lengths up to 10 digits, both positive and negative.  I'm unsure why np.random.randint isn't behaving as expected within the udf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark assumes 32-bit integers.  Since the range of integers being generated (1111111111, 9999999999) includes integers too high to be represented by 32-bit, spark is interpreting the 64-bit integers incorrectly.  Using spark's LongType() or converting the integers to strings first both eliminate the problem.